# App struck on iPad while installing ipa from iTunes 11.1.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, ipa

My app got strucked on iPad while i try to install ipa from iTunes.I made an ipa from xcode 5.0.2. and my ipad ios version is 5.1.1.Will this be any problem to install ipa.
My ipa is installing more than 50% and from there its not moving further.

[image: MY app got struck here and not increasing]

Answer (score 0):

How are you installing your app from iTunes? There are many other ways to do it:

1. With Apple Configurator
2. From Xcode itself

In the newer version of iOS, I believe that you are able to remove apps that are stuck like this, but in iOS 5, I will try to restart the device and then just tap and hold until it wiggles then remove it manually. Then try to use Xcode or Apple Configurator.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my issue by changing Architecture "Standard architectures(including 64-bit)(armv7,armv7s,armv64)" To "Standard architectures(armv7,armv7s)"

I Though problem is with my provision profile or iTunes.But my problem solved by just changing Architecures in Build Settings.

[image]